# Why doesn't this MongoDB error function work correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to make a connection to a Mongo database, should there be a connection error I need it to send an email notifying me. This is contained within the `email()` function.

Here is the code I have been trying:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://server:port/";

MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true}, async (err, db) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("my_collection");

}, async function (err) {
    console.log("No database connection");
    email("Database is down")
});
```

It's fairly simple, should the connection fail I want it to send me the email. However if I run this when there is a connection to the db it runs the `(err)` function and sends the email, I only want it to run when there is no db connection.

Comment: Note that you're passing 4 arguments to `MongoClient.connect`, when it only takes three…

Comment: `if (err) { console.log("No database connection");  email("Database is down"); } else { var dbo = db.db("my_collection"); ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a second callback, which does not exist in the [Mongo Node Native API](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/MongoClient.html#.connect) and therefore will not be used.

Instead, use the first callback and check if your `err` parameter is not null:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://server:port/";

MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true}, async (err, db) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("No database connection");
        email("Database is down")
        return;
    }
    var dbo = db.db("my_collection");
});
```